# symfony1 doctrine form submit - where to inject logic

Tags: php, forms, doctrine, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I've got a simple form that includes an input that will take money, i.e. float. So far it can accept a well-formed decimal only, e.g. `12768.56`. The task to inject some server-side logic (no javascript here) that would intercept the input value, like `12 768,56`, replace it with `12768.56` and let symfony/doctrine do its work. The transformation is just an example and I'ev got what I need, but the question is - **where should I put the intercepting function**? I guess it should be somehwere in the *XxxForm.class.php*. But I don't know which method. `doSave`? `processData`? I'm pretty sure there is a special place for that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put these kind of logics into a custom validator:

```
class myValidatorMoney extends sfValidatorNumber {

  protected function doClean($value) {
    $clean = $this->processNumber($value); // your logic in this function
    if($clean === false) { // if not possible to process
      throw new sfValidatorError($this, 'invalid', array('value' => $value));
    }
    return parent::doClean($clean);
  }
}
```

This way it works better with symfony forms, `updateXXXColumn()` works with valid values, but there's not much you can do with invalid input.

Comment: it seems strange to make validator change input. Asaik validators should return either true or false stating whether input is valid or not. Seems like violating the design?

Comment: Input has to be preprocessed before being validated, else validator can't validate. And this is symfony's way, to join preprocessors and validators. Validator shouldn't only tell if input is valid, but also what is wrong with it, eg not long enough, invalid characters, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the source code of `sfFormDoctrine` class: http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/form/sfFormDoctrine.class.php. There is a fragment there:

```
153   /**
154    * Processes cleaned up values with user defined methods.
155    *
156    * To process a value before it is used by the updateObject() method,
157    * you need to define an updateXXXColumn() method where XXX is the PHP name
158    * of the column.
159    *
160    * The method must return the processed value or false to remove the value
161    * from the array of cleaned up values.
162    *
163    * @see sfFormObject
164    */
165   public function processValues($values)
```

that says that one shall implement `updateXXXColumn()` method in the doctrine form class. And so I did:

```
// lib/form/doctrine/XxxForm.class.php
+  protected function updateAmountColumn($value)
+  {
+    return Tools::processMoneyStrToFloat($value);
+  }
```

Works perfectly.